# Como conseguir um resultado tipo n1 + n2 + n... = x?

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo programação em C online e escrevi este código para encontrar os números perfeitos em dado intervalo, porém gostaria de mostrar o resultado com a soma dos divisores, por exemplo :

```
1 + 2 + 3 = 6 PERFECT !!!
1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28 PERFECT !!!
```

Meu código está assim :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int first_interval;
    int last_interval;
    int number;
    int divider;
    int sum = 0;

    printf ("Enter first and last interval`s number\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &first_interval, &last_interval);

    for (number = first_interval; number >= first_interval && number <= last_interval; number++ ) {
        for (divider = 1; divider < number; divider++) {
            if (number % divider == 0) {
                sum = sum + divider;

            }

        }

        if (sum == number) {
            printf("%d = %d PERFECT !!!\n", number, sum);
        }

        sum = 0;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Como posso obter o resultado desejado, alguém tem alguma idéia?

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira bem simples de se fazer isso é armazenar em um vetor auxiliar os divisores do número e, se for perfeito, exibí-los. A principal limitação é que o número de divisores estará limitado pelo tamanho do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  int first_interval;
  int last_interval;
  int number;
  int divider;
  int sum = 0;

  // Define um vetor para armazer os divisores:
  int dividers[10] = {0};

  // Variável de controle para os divisores:
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter first and last interval`s number\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &first_interval, &last_interval);

  for (number = first_interval; number >= first_interval && number <= last_interval; number++ )
  { 
    for (divider = 1; divider < number; divider++)
    {
      if (number % divider == 0)
      {
        sum = sum + divider;

        // Encontrou um divisor, então armazena-o:
        dividers[i++] = divider;
      }
    }

    if (sum == number)
    {
      // Número é perfeito, então exibe os divisores:
      for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) printf("%d + ", dividers[j]);
      printf("%d = ", dividers[i-1]);

      printf("%d PERFECT !!!\n", number);
    }

    // Reinicia a variável de controle:
    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/95Ii71) para o intervalo entre 1 e 500, o resultado esperado é 6, 28 e 496.

O número 496 já possui 9 divisores, então é esse é o máximo que o programa pode chegar. O próximo número seria 8128, que possui 14 divisores (mais que o tamanho do vetor).

É possível contornar esta limitação utilizando alocação dinâmica de memória, mas isso fica como um desafio futuro para você, visto que (aparentemente) está iniciando os estudos em C agora.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, ainda não cheguei em vetores, mas já vou pesquisar como utilizá-los (seria array em inglês ? ).

Comment: Sim, seria o equivalente ao *array* em inglês.